# Trying to find a better way of finding something rather then looping through list from top to bottom.

Tags: java, performance

I am having a slight issue here, i am trying to think of a faster way of finding two elements from 2 different lists that match. The problem is that if i have lists which both have 1000 elements ( rules ) and the very last one [index.1000] matches then in order to find it i have to loop through booth lists from top to bottom. What i have is fine and it works however its not very efficient. Could any one perhaps suggest a better way ? (if there is any ? )

The loop in this meethod is where the iteration through the lists happen. For furthere reference below this method you will find what ContextRule and Context is.

```
public ContextRule match(Context messageContext, ContextRuleList contextRules) {
    ContextRule matchedContextRule = null;

    for(ContextRule contextRule : contextRules) {
        if(this.match(messageContext, contextRule)) {
            matchedContextRule = contextRule;
            break;
        }
    }       
    if(matchedContextRule == null) {
        matchedContextRule = this.getDefaultContextRule();
    }       
    return matchedContextRule;
}
```

match() method which does comparason.

```
private boolean match(Context messageContext, ContextRule contextRule) {
        return match(contextRule.getMessageContext().getUser(), messageContext.getUser())
                && match(contextRule.getMessageContext().getApplication(), messageContext.getApplication())
                && match(contextRule.getMessageContext().getService(), messageContext.getService())
                && match(contextRule.getMessageContext().getOperation(), messageContext.getOperation());
    }

    private boolean match(String value, String contextValue) {
        return value.equals(ContextRuleEvaluator.WILDCARD) || value.equals(contextValue);
    }
```

---

Context ( which is an interface )

```
public interface Context {    
  public String getUser();      
  public void setUser(String user);      
  public String getApplication();      
  public void setApplication(String application);      
  public String getService();      
  public void setService(String service);      
  public String getOperation();      
  public void setOperation(String operation);
}
```

And finally ContextRule

```
public interface ContextRule {
  public Context getMessageContext();  
  public int getAllowedConcurrentRequests();  
}
```

any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can your context rules be precomputed into any sort of hierarchical match tree once at application initialization?

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<ContextRule>>> contextRuleMap

public boolean match (Context context, Map<String, Map<String, List<ContextRule>> contextRuleMap)
{
    Map<String, List<ContextRule>> rulesByApplication = contextRuleMap[context.getUser()];

    for (ContextRule contextRule : rulesByApplication[context.getApplication()]) {
         // Existing logic for remaining 'match' of service and operation
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can pre-compute your 'match tree' to as many 'levels deep' as you need to by User -> Application -> Service -> Operation to achieve the necessary performance.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, so, your `match` function can be shortened to this:

```
public ContextRule match(Context messageContext, ContextRuleList contextRules) {
    for(ContextRule contextRule : contextRules) {
        if(this.match(messageContext, contextRule)) {
            return contextRule;
        }
    }       

    // Found nothing, returning default.
    return this.getDefaultContextRule();
}
```

This will not yield a massive performance improvement, but is easier to read.